# Laravel throws an error once I have more than 15 rows in my order table ```local.ERROR: Undefined array key 0```

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I really don't know how to put it. I have two tables `Order.php` and `Product.php`, a `return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'id');` in `Order.php` and `return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'product_id');` in `Product.php`.

In my `OrderController`

```
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::latest()->paginate(10);
    return view('admin.order.order')->with([
        'orders' => $orders,
    ]);
}
```

in my view

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
    <tr data-href="{{ route('orders.view', $order->id) }}">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ $order->products[0]->product_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->order_quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->customer_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->customer_tel_no }}</td>
        <td width="300">{{ $order->customer_address }} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</td>
        <td>{{ $order->total_amount }}</td>
        <td>
            <span class="badge text-white badge-lg bg-{{ $order->is_delivered == false ? 'warning' : 'success' }}">
                {{ $order->is_delivered == false ? 'Not yet delivered!' : 'Delivered!' }}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>{{ $order->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Everything works fine until, when I have more than 15 records in the orders table I get an error `Undefined array key 0`

And please I'm also new to Laravel thanks

Comment: It would seem that you have, at least, one `Order` without `Products`.

Comment: @nitrin0 all my fields are required

Comment: Where did you find the variable `$orders` in your foreach ?

Comment: @dcodes the code you presented begs to differ, `$order->products[0]` seems the only place where this can happen. Test if for null/empty and/or dump it and see it.

Comment: @workservice @nitrin() Sorry I added the wrong method/function in controller. I have updated it to the right one

Comment: @dcodes as the others commented, the problem states that the product with index 0 cannot be found so it throws an error. Either check the database or add ?? false into your code

Comment: @workservice I just made the changes now I'm getting a different ```Attempt to read property "product_name" on null```

Comment: @dcodes Well it is sure you have an order without products. Maybe you added it while testing or so. Did you do exactly this? `<td>{{ $order->products[0]->product_name ?? false }}</td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think this happens because of the line:

`<td>{{ $order->products[0]->product_name }}</td>`

Are you sure you have a product for every order?

This error would be because an $order does not have any products, therefore would have no array key 0

You can make use use php's new optional syntax while chaining which is `?->` https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-nullsafe-operator

`$order->products?->first()->product_name` which should return null, if there aren't any products on this particular $order (assuming you are using php 8!)

If you are on an older version of php you should consider

```
@if(count($order->products))
<td>{{ $order->products[0]->product_name }}</td>
@endif
```

Yet another approach would be, to use laravel's `optional()` helper like below

`<td>{{ optional($order->products)->first()->product_name }} </td>`

Comment: Or `<td>{{ $order->products[0]->product_name ?? false }}</td>`

Comment: I just made the changes now I'm getting a different ```Attempt to read property "product_name" on null```

Comment: Which solution did you apply?

Comment: @UchivaruKanda ```<td>{{ $order->products[0]->product_name ?? false }}</td>```

Comment: @dcodes I think you should give a try to the other two solutions, let me know

Comment: coming back to this `<td>{{ $order->products[0]->product_name ?? false }}</td> `this solution does not work because of the array syntax I think if you were to use the collection helper `->first()` instead of `[0]` it should